# AngularJS - accessing ng-click in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to get my head around directives, i can easily use the template function to throw out my HTML, however, if i have an ng-click within my template, how can i access it within the link function?

My directive:

```
app.directive('directiveScroll', function () {
return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template:   '<div class="scroll-btns">' +
            '<div class="arrow-left" ng-click="scrollLeft(sectionID)"></div>' +
            '<div class="arrow-right" ng-click="scrollRight(sectionID)"></div>' +
        '</div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $scope.scrollRight  = function () {
          console.log("scrollRight  clicked");
        };
        $scope.scrollLeft  = function () {
          console.log("scrollLeft  clicked");
        };
      }
  };
});
```

As you can see, i have added `$scope.scrollRight` to my `link` function, however on click, nothing appears in the console.

If i place:

```
$scope.scrollRight  = function () {
     console.log("scrollRight  clicked");
};

$scope.scrollLeft  = function () {
     console.log("scrollLeft  clicked");
};
```

In my controller (and out of my directive), it works as expected.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @proxygear: It is not a typo. It is a lack of understanding on the users part at the time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your link function is defined like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {..}
```

however you are writing functions on `$scope` variable:

```
    $scope.scrollRight  = function () {
      console.log("scrollRight  clicked");
    };
    $scope.scrollLeft  = function () {
      console.log("scrollLeft  clicked");
    };
```

In this case $scope is not actually injected into link function (and can't be injected), so link is just simple function with parameters. You should change `$scope` to `scope` and it should work:

```
    scope.scrollRight  = function () {
      console.log("scrollRight  clicked");
    };
    scope.scrollLeft  = function () {
      console.log("scrollLeft  clicked");
    };
```

Comment: thats seems to have worked, and how do i access the sectionID i am passing on the ngClick in my scrollRight/Left function?

Comment: `scope.scrollLeft  = function (param) { console.log(param); };` this works the same as plain JS - passing params to functions corresponds to parameters in function declaration

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the link function parameter is named `scope`, not `$scope`?

Comment: @threed I know... Actually I meant the parameter name was different from what is used below in the code, if you take a closer look... And I believe it was the root cause.