# Attach ng-click with angular js directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive & attach `ng-click` with the template.
So I expecting that if I click on the template it will log the statement from `scope.scrollElem` function, which is not happening.

I am able to create the directive but it is not responding to click.

**Design approch**

If this directive is attached to this DOM element, it will insert a `div` element before & after this DOM. This inserted `div` have an image (want to attach ng-click to this image) which will respond to an event.

**Directive module**

```
//rest of code
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: _controller,
    link: _link
 }
};
```

**Link function**

```
function _link(scope, elem, attrs) {
    console.log("Method Executing:Navigator._link");
    var params = scope.$eval(attrs.navparams);
    //Separate function is used to create template as 
    //the template is dependent on params value 
    scope.createNavigatorTemplate = _createNavigatorTemplate(scope, elem, params);
    scope.scrollElem = function() {
            console.log("abc");
        }
}
```

**Creating template**

```
function _createNavigatorTemplate(scope, elem, params, $compile) {
    params.forEach(function(item) {
        var _template = angular.element('<div class="' + item.class + '"></div>');
        var _img = angular.element('<img>').attr({
            src: item.image,
            alt: item.imageAlt,
            'ng-click':"scrollElem()" // attaching ng-click here
        });
         //appending template with element
         //_img.bind('ng-click',scope._scrollElem) //tried this but not working
        _appendTemplate(elem, item.dir, _template);
    })
}
```

I checked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363217/angularjs-accessing-ng-click-in-custom-directive) but still not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you explain in general what you're trying to achieve think you're using a screwdriver as a hammer here maybe.  Things like `'<div class="' + item.class + '"</div>'` can be easily done with bindings in the view instead, without running the element through $compile and passing a scope to the returned link function any directives on it won't be processed.

Comment: @shaunhusain I have added the design approach, you can check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the template before linking so that it gets compiled properly:

```js
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
  return {
    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      var params = scope.$eval(attrs.navparams);
      //Separate function is used to create template as 
      //the template is dependent on params value 
      scope.createNavigatorTemplate = _createNavigatorTemplate(scope, elem, params);
      scope.scrollElem = function() {
        console.log("abc");
      }
    },
    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      console.log("Method Executing:Navigator._link");

    }
  }
}
```

---

Based on your approach, it looks like you are looking for a e directive having [`ngTransclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

Basically you'll create a directive with your divs contaning images and transclude the content between it, like:

```html
<div><img></div>
<div ng-translude>Content will be added here</div>
<div><img></div>
```

Which you can use like `<my-directive>My content</my-direcive>`

and the output will be

```
<div><img></div>
<div ng-translude>My Content</div>
<div><img></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add div in template

```
function _createNavigatorTemplate(scope, elem, params, $compile) {
params.forEach(function(item) {
    var _template = angular.element('<div class="' + item.class + '"</div>');
    var _img = angular.element('<img>').attr({
        src: item.image,
        alt: item.imageAlt,
         template: '<div class="arrow-left" ng-click="scrollElem()"></div>',
    });
     //appending template with element
     //_img.bind('ng-click',scope._scrollElem) //tried this but not working
    _appendTemplate(elem, item.dir, _template);
})
```

}